# Management of the shopping cart in ios application

Tags: ios, shopping-cart

I am implementing iOS app with a shopping cart. After spending  all sending data to a server with JSON, but when the user filling the shopping cart as I can store the data? I must use the PList or do I build a local database type SQlite in the application? Do you have any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the data needs to be live and not persisted across launches, store it in an array (NSArray or NSMutableArray), most likely the mutable one. When the user is done, structure it however you want and send via JSON.

If you need to store across launches, then use Coredata.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mEAav7dM4hk

Plist is not meant for this...